# Emails sent using python SMTP lib doesn't reach recipient

Tags: python, email, smtp, gmail, smtplib

I have a problem using Python to send emails. The purpose of this script is that it should load all .PDF files from a specified folder and send the first file to the first email in a .CSV file and so on. This works fine, on my end, the emails appear in my sent-box at gmail.com containing the correct attachment.

On the other end, the recipients that are meant to recieve these emails doesn't get them. I've also checked the spam-boxes of these emails but they are no where to be found.

- Anyone have clue why?
- Also, if I send to my email, the mails reach my inbox.

Here is a part of the code where I think things goes wrong:

```
    #imports
    import smtplib
    from email.mime.text import MIMEText
    from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
    from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
    from email import encoders

    counter = 0
    for mailTo in emailRecList:

      try:
        #server connection
        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
        server.starttls()
        server.login(loginMail, loginPassword)

        #__Send email__
        server.sendmail(sendMail,loginMail,email)
        server.quit
        counter = counter + 1 
      except smtplib.SMTPException:
        print('Failed to send mail to: ' + mailTo)
```

Comment: That's a lot of code. Can you please try to narrow it down to only what you think is relevant? And some basic troubleshooting: You made sure the response from your SMTP server signals that the mail was sent? Did you use the correct credentials?

Comment: @YotamSalmon He said they show up in his `Sent` mailbox on gmail, so it must be connecting to the SMTP server correctly. Most likely the mail is being blocked by the receiver's spam filter.

Comment: `dirDivider = '/'` ? Why aren't you using `os.path.join()`?

Comment: Of course I missed that. Thanks, @Barmar

Comment: Ohh I will use os.join.path() in the future, didn't know about that one.
Is there anything that should be done to tell the mail adress "this is not spam"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually quite embarrassing, but this is what's wrong:

```
server.sendmail(sendMail,loginMail,email)
```

it should be:

```
server.sendmail(loginMail,mailTo,email)
```

I would guess the reason it said that the mails where sent to the recipient was that it was defined as so in the:

`msg = MIMEMultipart()`
`msg['To'] = mailTo`